# Incorrect message length when using C python api

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-extensions

I'm trying to extend libhydrogen (open source found here: https://github.com/jedisct1/libhydrogen/) to support calls to the underlying library in Python. However, I ran into a strange issue.
Specifically I have the following code:

```
static PyObject* crypto_secretbox_encrypt(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    char* m;
    size_t mlen;
    uint64_t msg_id;
    char *ctx;
    size_t ctx_len;
    const uint8_t *key; //this shouldn't matter its secret
    size_t key_len;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#|K|s#|s#", &m, &mlen, &msg_id, &ctx, &ctx_len, &key, &key_len); //only s# accepts null bytes, need to random pointers to store lengths
    //printf("Parsed \n");
    //printf("MSG: %s, MSG_ID: %" PRIu64 ", CTX: %s\n", m, msg_id, ctx);
    if(ctx_len != hydro_secretbox_CONTEXTBYTES){
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Context not of correct size: Received %lu bytes", ctx_len);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(key_len != hydro_secretbox_KEYBYTES){
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "Key not of correct size: Received %lu bytes", key_len);
        return NULL;
    }
```

Which is able to successfully parse the length of ctx, however, when it gets to the key it gets thrown the error,

```
  File "cryptotest.py", line 7, in <module>
    c1 = crypto.secretbox_encrypt("message1", 0, "\x00"*8, '\x00'*32);
ValueError: Key not of correct size: Received 140123308032032 bytes
```

Any ideas on why I'm unable to successfully parse the key length?

Answer (score 2):

You've specified the length as a `size_t`. The `s#` format does not take a `size_t`. [It takes an `int` or `Py_ssize_t`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#strings-and-buffers), depending on whether the `PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` macro was `#define`d before including `Python.h`.

> **Note:** For all `#` variants of formats (`s#`, `y#`, etc.), the type of the length argument (int or `Py_ssize_t`) is controlled by defining the macro `PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` before including `Python.h`. If the macro was defined, length is a `Py_ssize_t` rather than an `int`. This behavior will change in a future Python version to only support `Py_ssize_t` and drop `int` support. It is best to always define `PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN`.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I was casting to the wrong data type and that was a potential issue, which I assume some type conversion messes up the value of number when it gets parsed. I can't find documentation on Py_ssize_t, but would I be able to just cast to size_t without an issue?

Comment: @HansonDuan: The closest thing to documentation for `Py_ssize_t` is [PEP 353](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/), which specifies it as the same size as `size_t` but signed, and as a typedef for `ssize_t` when `ssize_t` is available.